# Output Device change to headphone automatically sometimes when I turn on the computer

Tags: sound

Sometimes when I turn on the computer, even though I don't have the headphone connected, the ubuntu change the device to the headphone and I always have to go into the settings and change to the speaker manually. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you remove headphones after you shutdown your ubuntu before?